# Chemical formula inside pgfplot rendered wrong---labels overlap

Tags: pgfplots, chemformula

Under normal circumstances `\ch{AB_2}` is rendered as `$AB_2$`, but not inside the `pgfplot`. I am getting the error message `Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number` and labels overlap. Is it somehow possible to make these 2 packages to be friends. I am still learning `PGF`, therefore such naive question. I would appreciate your any input.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,chemformula,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    N   system     A1          C2       Exp
    1     CH2     -0.70      -0.82     -0.53 
    2     NH3     -0.97      -1.58      0.00 
    3    H2HO     -0.96      -1.53     -0.06 
    4    SiH2      0.11      -0.92     -0.60 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=eV,ylabel=eV]
        \addplot[
                visualization depends on={value \thisrow{system} \as \label},           
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                nodes near coords*={\ch{\label}}]
         table[x=Exp,y=A1]{data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a purely pgfplots problem. You're mixing the `point meta` (synonym for `scatter src`) and `visualization depends on`. But `point meta` is used to pass extra data in a standard way, while `visualization depends on` is used to give extra data *without* interfering with `point meta`, and how you use it is completely up to you.

**Solution 1** Pass the labels as `point meta` (here with `scatter src`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,chemformula,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    N   system     A1          C2       Exp
    1     CH2     -0.70      -0.82     -0.53 
    2     NH3     -0.97      -1.58      0.00 
    3    H2HO     -0.96      -1.53     -0.06 
    4    SiH2      0.11      -0.92     -0.60 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=eV,ylabel=eV]
        \addplot[
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                nodes near coords={\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
                ]
         table[x=Exp,y=A1,meta=system]{data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I used the `meta` key to specify the `point meta` column. The `\expandafter` trickery is apparently necessary to typeset the chemical formula with `\ch` if the formula text is in a macro (like `\label` here).  Also note that there is no asterisk after `nodes near coords`: otherwise pgfplots will apply a default style to the nodes that expects numerical values in `point meta`.

**Solution 2** Pass labels with `visualization depends on`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,chemformula,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    N   system     A1          C2       Exp
    1     CH2     -0.70      -0.82     -0.53
    2     NH3     -0.97      -1.58      0.00
    3    H2HO     -0.96      -1.53     -0.06
    4    SiH2      0.11      -0.92     -0.60
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=eV,ylabel=eV]
        \addplot[
                scatter, only marks,
                nodes near coords={\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\label}},
                visualization depends on={value \thisrow{system} \as \label},           
                ]
         table[x=Exp,y=A1]{data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I'm not using `scatter src` here (i.e. no `point meta`). In both this solution and the previous one we have some overlap of the text labels...

**Solution 3** Use `visualization depends on` to give the label text **and** `point meta` to set the label position:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,chemformula,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    N   system     A1          C2       Exp    Position
    1     CH2     -0.70      -0.82     -0.53   1
    2     NH3     -0.97      -1.58      0.00   1
    3    H2HO     -0.96      -1.53     -0.06   -1
    4    SiH2      0.11      -0.92     -0.60   -1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=eV,ylabel=eV]
        \addplot[
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit,
                nodes near coords align=vertical,
                nodes near coords={\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\label}},
                visualization depends on={value \thisrow{system} \as \label},           
                ]
         table[x=Exp,y=A1,meta=Position]{data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I added a data column with a value as expected by the key `nodes near coords align=vertical`. Note the use of `scatter src=explicit`: we give `point meta` from the table data but this time as numerical data.

Comment: Dear Jeremie, I tried all your solutions, rather different results are produced: 1) is not possible to compile with xelatex; 2) labels overlap; 3) a clear plot.  Do you know what could wrong with (1)?

Comment: @yarchik, I have no errors when compiling the three examples with xelatex. Which error do you get? Note that solution 1 also has the overlap anyway. For solution 3, does "clear plot" mean it's good, or that nothing is shown? (in that case, do you get an error message?)

Comment: @yarchik, I just noticed I dropped the last line (`\end{document}`) in the solution 1 copy-paste (fixed now).

Comment: Everything is fine !